# Cleaning and copying data from multiple json files into one json file

Tags: python, json, file, twitter, copy

New user here. 
I am doing some work on (twitter) json data using python.

I want to read each lines from multiple json files in a directory and copy only the lines i want into a new json file. I want to copy the data having the "created_at" time and discard the data having "deleted" data.

```
import json
import os

path = ''
filelist = os.listdir(path)

towrite = ''


for filename in filelist:
    if filename.endswith(".json"):
        with open(path + filename, 'r') as file:
            lines = file.readlines()
            for line in lines:
                try:


                    if line.startswith('{"created_at":'):
                        towrite += json.dumps(json.loads(line)) + '\n'
                        with open('01_00_clean.json', 'w') as file:
                            file.write(towrite)

                except ValueError:
                    pass
```

The code would run but wont copy the data into the new file. Can anyone please help me with the program?

Comment: Is the new file even being created? If so - is anything put inside it to start with?

Comment: use 'a' append mode instead of 'w' mode. It will erase everything in your file every time. Append mode will not. Also, are you sure the condition is being satisfied above the file creation?

Comment: Also you should never silently `pass` any exception. At least log that an exception occured.

Comment: You only want to copy the information held by "created_at" or you want to copy the full json item that contains a key "created_at"?

Comment: I want to copy some of the json item that contains the key "created_at".